# Setting gradient programmatically

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set a linear-gradient background for an element using an array of computed swatches.

Currently, I have this stylesheet (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/pz18892x/1/)):

```
.element
    background linear-gradient(180deg, #92c3ff, #ff8e87, #fcfb83)
    background-size 600% 600%
    animation BackgroundAnimation 20s ease infinite

@keyframes BackgroundAnimation
   0% {
   background-position 50% 0
   }
   50% {
   background-position 50% 100%
   }
   100% {
   background-position 50% 0
   }
```

Instead of hard-coding the colours in the stylesheet as shown above, I want to use an array of computed swatches instead. The swatches are computed with the help of [Vibrant.js](https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js), as follows:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', './path/to/image.png');

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
var swatches = vibrant.swatches();
for (var swatch in swatches)
if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
```

I can easily set the background color (a solid, single color) of the selected element, like this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".element");

element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.DarkVibrantSwatch.getHex();

// element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.VibrantSwatch.getHex();
// element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.MutedSwatch.getHex();
// element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.DarkMutedSwatch.getHex();
// element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.LightMutedSwatch.getHex();
```

However, how could I possibly set a gradient with all the existing swatches instead of a single color background? Furthermore, how would I go about to animate it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand it. You mean you have an array of all three colors of the gradient (and its angle is also there in some variable) and you want to set the gradient to an element using those?

Comment: The first part of the question is perhaps confusing. It's just an example of the result I am attempting to attain. I basically want to generate an animated gradient from a set of computed swatches. I'm being able to compute the swatches, what I'm not being able to do is to use them to generate the gradient. The last two blocks of code is what matters most in this question really: I'm able to set a background from one single swatch for the element `.element` on the last block with  `element.style.backgroundColor = vibrant.DarkVibrantSwatch.getHex();`, but how do I set a gradient and animate it?

Comment: Ok, here is the way to set a gradient to an element programatically - https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/r02vgp5s/ Does it help you? Also, what do you mean by animating it? How exactly should the animation be?

Comment: Assuming you have numerical values for the colours, you'd need to decide on the number of steps it takes to transition from one swatch to another. You would then need to either (a) break each colour value up into its 3 component parts or (b) convert the colour to an HSL representation. From there it's just a matter of doing a linear interpolation between the RGB/HSL values of one swatch and the next (i.e, 3 simultaneous interpolations). You could use Harry's method of setting the gradient at each step. (cont)

Comment: (cont) An RGB gradient looks a bit different to an HSL one - the transition would be a gradient in time, rather than in space. At each step in time, you're showing a gradient in space - dunno whether borwsers use an RGB or an HSL interpolation between each of the stops of the gradient.

Comment: @enhzflep thanks for the hint. Could you specify with an example?

Comment: @pierrebonbon - You're welcome. It's precisely because I'm not in a position to devote the required time to create a worked example that I left the two comments describing the process. Where are you stuck in the effort of implementing something yourself?

Comment: @enhzflep I thought you might know of any existing implementation. ;-) I am working on a jsfiddle and will post it here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
  var swatches = vibrant.swatches();
  for (var swatch in swatches)
    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) 
     console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex());

      var gradColors = [
      vibrant.DarkVibrantSwatch.getHex(),
      vibrant.VibrantSwatch.getHex(),
      vibrant.MutedSwatch.getHex(),
      vibrant.DarkMutedSwatch.getHex(),
      vibrant.LightMutedSwatch.getHex()
      ];

      console.log(gradColors);

      var element = document.querySelector('.element');

      element.style.background = 'linear-gradient(180deg,' + gradColors.join() + ')';
      element.style.backgroundSize = '600% 600%';
      element.style.animation = 'BackgroundAnimation 5s ease infinite';

});
```

First, it computes the dominant colors of a given image (it uses [Vibrant.js](https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js) to accomplish this), then sets a background gradient for `.element` and animates it. It does this by accessing some of its style properties, namely [background](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp) and [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animation.asp).

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/pz18892x/42/)

Comment: Ah, of course! Leverage the CSS engine to do the work for you - it seems so obvious now. Good job, you should accept the answer (you can accept your own answers)

Comment: Yes, well there was no reason here to do everything in javascript (the title isn't entirely clear perhaps). @Harry's answer above got me into the right direction anyway, in terms of accessing the style properties directly from the script and converting the color array to a string with the [Array join method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).